# Trying to understand the options in TWRP backup

Tags: twrp

This is a screenshot of the twrp screen after you choose "Backup":

[image]

I have the following questions:

1. What is the difference between the options "Boot, System and Data" on one hand, and "System Image" on the other?
2. Is the "Data" option for data of system apps and user apps, or only system apps?
3. I want to take a backup so that I can get a file that I can flash with Odin (that is, without requiring twrp). Which option should I use?
4. What is "Vendor Image", and how does it differ from "System Image"?
5. What is the difference between "Vendor" and "Vendor Image"?

Comment: These are all partition names, see details here: https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/info-android-device-partitions-basic-t3586565

Comment: @IrfanLatif That link mentions the partitions, but my questions #1, #2, #3 and #5 remain unanswered.

Comment: `Image` is `dd` backup i.e. the exact copy of whole partition (to retain Verified Boot), the other one is `tar` backup i.e. the contents of filesystem. I don't think restoring TWRP backup through odin would be possible but I never used Samsung device. May be the Images can be restored. All of the remaining questions are answered once you know what these partitions contain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. as Irfan pointed out in his comment, "Image" means creating a partition image (using `dd`). Normally, TWRP creates tar archives with all the files *located on* a given partition, which then is much smaller.
2. "Data" contains *all* data – i.e. data & configuration from system apps as well as user apps. As the `/system` partition is mounted read-only during normal operation, that's where all "variable data" go (apart from files you store to the SD card).
3. Probably none of those. It's unlikely Odin understands any of the TWRP backups (you can try, and I stand corrected if you find out it can – but no guarantees from my side, including that it doesn't "brick" your device – I'm not a Samsung user)
4. Vendor is stuff very specific to your device provided by the "vendor", i.e. usually the manufacturer (including customizations) – while System is the "Android base" (though this separation is rarely absolute)
5. Same as between "System" and "System Image" (see 1.)