# If I buy a used and infected android phone, will flashing a new custom recovery and custom ROM make it safe to use?

Tags: recovery-mode, custom-roms, malware, virus

If I buy a used and infected phone with a expensive spyware on it that the antivirus does not detect or is unable to remove than will flashing a new custom recovery and custom ROM make it safe to use?

What would be the proper way of doing it?
Connect to computer and install new recovery first and then the rom or some other way?

Once I have done these two steps, can I be assured that my phone is clean?

And should I be worried about getting my computer infected?

**Edit:** If this is not enough then what other actions should I take to be sure that the phone is clean?

Comment: the proper way is find the right flash tool and stock rom before buying. custom rom depends on stock rom firmware

Comment: No, you can't be sure. The recovery and the system partition are the two most important partitions but not the only one. There are also Bootloader, RIL, plus device specific partitions.

Comment: @Robert : So what would be the proper way to rewrite all the partitions?

Comment: as i said just flashing stock ROM and you will be fine. it will not harm your pc

Comment: @Linux_user0987 That is device dependent. There is no general way to flash a Android partition respectively system image.

Comment: @Robert : 1) How can I find out how many partitions my device has? 2) Is it possible to rewrite all partitions for a device. And by that I mean is there any brand which has images of all partitions available on the internet?

Comment: partitions explained [Mediatek](https://blog.csdn.net/zhangbijun1230/article/details/81092381) very good explanation of android partitions on xda-developers [Qualcomm](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/215683/trying-to-understand-the-options-in-twrp-backup#comment276228_215683)

Comment: if you download full stock ROM it comes with all required partitions except device unique calibration data, carrier sim lock, imei, mac address, ... you must not wipe these (nvram, persist, protect, seccfg, ...) you can list partitions from `fastboot getvar all` (in fastboot mode) or from `adb shell ls -l /dev/block/*/*/*/by-name/*` (with usb-debugging)