# What is the new mmcblk0?

Tags: adb, stock-android, partitions, android-11, oxygenos

> The device is OnePlus 8 Pro, it is completely functional, booted for root ADB from LineageOS Recovery via `fastboot -s XXXXXXXX boot lineage-recovery.img`.
>
> ```
> $ adb --version
> Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
> Version 31.0.2-7242960
> Installed as /opt/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb
> ```

Trying to follow some 4-6 years old online guides & QnAs (mostly written by Irfan Latif) on how to backup stock ROM & partitions using `adb pull` or `adb exec-out`.

All of these materials always reference an `mmcblk0` partition. But in my case it is missing.

What I have instead are these:

```
$ adb -s XXXXXXXX shell 'ls -al /dev/block' | grep -e '^[^d]'
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       37 1970-04-15 15:06 bootdevice -> /dev/block/platform/soc/XXXXXXX.ufshc
brw-------  1 root root   7,   0 1970-04-15 15:06 loop0
brw-------  1 root root   7,   8 1970-04-15 15:06 loop1
brw-------  1 root root   7,  80 1970-04-15 15:06 loop10
brw-------  1 root root   7,  88 1970-04-15 15:06 loop11
brw-------  1 root root   7,  96 1970-04-15 15:06 loop12
brw-------  1 root root   7, 104 1970-04-15 15:06 loop13
brw-------  1 root root   7, 112 1970-04-15 15:06 loop14
brw-------  1 root root   7, 120 1970-04-15 15:06 loop15
brw-------  1 root root   7,  16 1970-04-15 15:06 loop2
brw-------  1 root root   7,  24 1970-04-15 15:06 loop3
brw-------  1 root root   7,  32 1970-04-15 15:06 loop4
brw-------  1 root root   7,  40 1970-04-15 15:06 loop5
brw-------  1 root root   7,  48 1970-04-15 15:06 loop6
brw-------  1 root root   7,  56 1970-04-15 15:06 loop7
brw-------  1 root root   7,  64 1970-04-15 15:06 loop8
brw-------  1 root root   7,  72 1970-04-15 15:06 loop9
brw-------  1 root root   1,   0 1970-04-15 15:06 ram0
brw-------  1 root root   1,   1 1970-04-15 15:06 ram1
brw-------  1 root root   1,  10 1970-04-15 15:06 ram10
brw-------  1 root root   1,  11 1970-04-15 15:06 ram11
brw-------  1 root root   1,  12 1970-04-15 15:06 ram12
brw-------  1 root root   1,  13 1970-04-15 15:06 ram13
brw-------  1 root root   1,  14 1970-04-15 15:06 ram14
brw-------  1 root root   1,  15 1970-04-15 15:06 ram15
brw-------  1 root root   1,   2 1970-04-15 15:06 ram2
brw-------  1 root root   1,   3 1970-04-15 15:06 ram3
brw-------  1 root root   1,   4 1970-04-15 15:06 ram4
brw-------  1 root root   1,   5 1970-04-15 15:06 ram5
brw-------  1 root root   1,   6 1970-04-15 15:06 ram6
brw-------  1 root root   1,   7 1970-04-15 15:06 ram7
brw-------  1 root root   1,   8 1970-04-15 15:06 ram8
brw-------  1 root root   1,   9 1970-04-15 15:06 ram9
brw-------  1 root root   8,   0 1970-04-15 15:06 sda
brw-------  1 root root   8,   1 1970-04-15 15:06 sda1
brw-------  1 root root   8,  10 1970-04-15 15:06 sda10
brw-------  1 root root   8,  11 1970-04-15 15:06 sda11
brw-------  1 root root   8,  12 1970-04-15 15:06 sda12
brw-------  1 root root   8,  13 1970-04-15 15:06 sda13
brw-------  1 root root   8,  14 1970-04-15 15:06 sda14
brw-------  1 root root   8,  15 1970-04-15 15:06 sda15
brw-------  1 root root 259,   0 1970-04-15 15:06 sda16
brw-------  1 root root 259,   1 1970-04-15 15:06 sda17
brw-------  1 root root 259,   2 1970-04-15 15:06 sda18
brw-------  1 root root 259,   3 1970-04-15 15:06 sda19
brw-------  1 root root   8,   2 1970-04-15 15:06 sda2
brw-------  1 root root 259,   4 1970-04-15 15:06 sda20
brw-------  1 root root 259,   5 1970-04-15 15:06 sda21
brw-------  1 root root 259,   6 1970-04-15 15:06 sda22
brw-------  1 root root 259,   7 1970-04-15 15:06 sda23
brw-------  1 root root   8,   3 1970-04-15 15:09 sda3
brw-------  1 root root   8,   4 1970-04-15 15:06 sda4
brw-------  1 root root   8,   5 1970-04-15 15:06 sda5
brw-------  1 root root   8,   6 1970-04-15 15:06 sda6
brw-------  1 root root   8,   7 1970-04-15 15:06 sda7
brw-------  1 root root   8,   8 1970-04-15 15:06 sda8
brw-------  1 root root   8,   9 1970-04-15 15:06 sda9
brw-------  1 root root   8,  16 1970-04-15 15:06 sdb
brw-------  1 root root   8,  17 1970-04-15 15:06 sdb1
brw-------  1 root root   8,  18 1970-04-15 15:06 sdb2
brw-------  1 root root   8,  32 1970-04-15 15:06 sdc
brw-------  1 root root   8,  33 1970-04-15 15:06 sdc1
brw-------  1 root root   8,  34 1970-04-15 15:06 sdc2
brw-------  1 root root   8,  48 1970-04-15 15:06 sdd
brw-------  1 root root   8,  49 1970-04-15 15:06 sdd1
brw-------  1 root root   8,  50 1970-04-15 15:06 sdd2
brw-------  1 root root   8,  51 1970-04-15 15:06 sdd3
brw-------  1 root root   8,  52 1970-04-15 15:06 sdd4
brw-------  1 root root   8,  64 1970-04-15 15:06 sde
brw-------  1 root root   8,  65 1970-04-15 15:06 sde1
brw-------  1 root root   8,  74 1970-04-15 15:06 sde10
brw-------  1 root root   8,  75 1970-04-15 15:06 sde11
brw-------  1 root root   8,  76 1970-04-15 15:06 sde12
brw-------  1 root root   8,  77 1970-04-15 15:06 sde13
brw-------  1 root root   8,  78 1970-04-15 15:06 sde14
brw-------  1 root root   8,  79 1970-04-15 15:06 sde15
brw-------  1 root root 259,   8 1970-04-15 15:06 sde16
brw-------  1 root root 259,   9 1970-04-15 15:06 sde17
brw-------  1 root root 259,  10 1970-04-15 15:06 sde18
brw-------  1 root root 259,  11 1970-04-15 15:06 sde19
brw-------  1 root root   8,  66 1970-04-15 15:06 sde2
brw-------  1 root root 259,  12 1970-04-15 15:06 sde20
brw-------  1 root root 259,  13 1970-04-15 15:06 sde21
brw-------  1 root root 259,  14 1970-04-15 15:06 sde22
brw-------  1 root root 259,  15 1970-04-15 15:06 sde23
brw-------  1 root root 259,  16 1970-04-15 15:06 sde24
brw-------  1 root root 259,  17 1970-04-15 15:06 sde25
brw-------  1 root root 259,  18 1970-04-15 15:06 sde26
brw-------  1 root root 259,  19 1970-04-15 15:06 sde27
brw-------  1 root root 259,  20 1970-04-15 15:06 sde28
brw-------  1 root root 259,  21 1970-04-15 15:06 sde29
brw-------  1 root root   8,  67 1970-04-15 15:06 sde3
brw-------  1 root root 259,  22 1970-04-15 15:06 sde30
brw-------  1 root root 259,  23 1970-04-15 15:06 sde31
brw-------  1 root root 259,  24 1970-04-15 15:06 sde32
brw-------  1 root root 259,  25 1970-04-15 15:06 sde33
brw-------  1 root root 259,  26 1970-04-15 15:06 sde34
brw-------  1 root root 259,  27 1970-04-15 15:06 sde35
brw-------  1 root root 259,  28 1970-04-15 15:06 sde36
brw-------  1 root root 259,  29 1970-04-15 15:06 sde37
brw-------  1 root root 259,  30 1970-04-15 15:06 sde38
brw-------  1 root root 259,  31 1970-04-15 15:06 sde39
brw-------  1 root root   8,  68 1970-04-15 15:06 sde4
brw-------  1 root root 259,  32 1970-04-15 15:06 sde40
brw-------  1 root root 259,  33 1970-04-15 15:06 sde41
brw-------  1 root root 259,  34 1970-04-15 15:06 sde42
brw-------  1 root root 259,  35 1970-04-15 15:06 sde43
brw-------  1 root root 259,  36 1970-04-15 15:06 sde44
brw-------  1 root root 259,  37 1970-04-15 15:06 sde45
brw-------  1 root root 259,  38 1970-04-15 15:06 sde46
brw-------  1 root root 259,  39 1970-04-15 15:06 sde47
brw-------  1 root root 259,  40 1970-04-15 15:06 sde48
brw-------  1 root root 259,  41 1970-04-15 15:06 sde49
brw-------  1 root root   8,  69 1970-04-15 15:06 sde5
brw-------  1 root root 259,  42 1970-04-15 15:06 sde50
brw-------  1 root root 259,  43 1970-04-15 15:06 sde51
brw-------  1 root root 259,  44 1970-04-15 15:06 sde52
brw-------  1 root root 259,  45 1970-04-15 15:06 sde53
brw-------  1 root root 259,  46 1970-04-15 15:06 sde54
brw-------  1 root root 259,  47 1970-04-15 15:06 sde55
brw-------  1 root root 259,  48 1970-04-15 15:06 sde56
brw-------  1 root root 259,  49 1970-04-15 15:06 sde57
brw-------  1 root root 259,  50 1970-04-15 15:06 sde58
brw-------  1 root root 259,  51 1970-04-15 15:06 sde59
brw-------  1 root root   8,  70 1970-04-15 15:06 sde6
brw-------  1 root root 259,  52 1970-04-15 15:06 sde60
brw-------  1 root root 259,  53 1970-04-15 15:06 sde61
brw-------  1 root root 259,  54 1970-04-15 15:06 sde62
brw-------  1 root root 259,  55 1970-04-15 15:06 sde63
brw-------  1 root root 259,  56 1970-04-15 15:06 sde64
brw-------  1 root root 259,  57 1970-04-15 15:06 sde65
brw-------  1 root root 259,  58 1970-04-15 15:06 sde66
brw-------  1 root root 259,  59 1970-04-15 15:06 sde67
brw-------  1 root root 259,  60 1970-04-15 15:06 sde68
brw-------  1 root root 259,  61 1970-04-15 15:06 sde69
brw-------  1 root root   8,  71 1970-04-15 15:06 sde7
brw-------  1 root root 259,  62 1970-04-15 15:06 sde70
brw-------  1 root root 259,  63 1970-04-15 15:06 sde71
brw-------  1 root root 259,  64 1970-04-15 15:06 sde72
brw-------  1 root root 259,  65 1970-04-15 15:06 sde73
brw-------  1 root root 259,  66 1970-04-15 15:06 sde74
brw-------  1 root root 259,  67 1970-04-15 15:06 sde75
brw-------  1 root root 259,  68 1970-04-15 15:06 sde76
brw-------  1 root root   8,  72 1970-04-15 15:06 sde8
brw-------  1 root root   8,  73 1970-04-15 15:06 sde9
brw-------  1 root root   8,  80 1970-04-15 15:06 sdf
brw-------  1 root root   8,  81 1970-04-15 15:06 sdf1
brw-------  1 root root   8,  82 1970-04-15 15:06 sdf2
brw-------  1 root root   8,  83 1970-04-15 15:06 sdf3
brw-------  1 root root   8,  84 1970-04-15 15:06 sdf4
brw-------  1 root root   8,  85 1970-04-15 15:06 sdf5
brw-------  1 root root   8,  86 1970-04-15 15:06 sdf6
brw-------  1 root root   8,  87 1970-04-15 15:06 sdf7
brw-------  1 root root   8,  88 1970-04-15 15:06 sdf8
brw-------  1 root root   8,  89 1970-04-15 15:06 sdf9
brw-------  1 root root 254,   0 1970-04-15 15:06 zram0
```

`by-name`:

```
$ adb -s XXXXXXXX shell 'ls -alpsh /dev/block/by-name'
total 0
0 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 2.4K 1970-04-15 15:06 ./
0 drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 3.1K 1970-04-15 15:06 ../
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 1970-04-15 15:06 ALIGN_TO_128K_1 -> /dev/block/sdd1
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 1970-04-15 15:06 ALIGN_TO_128K_2 -> /dev/block/sdf1
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 1970-04-15 15:06 abl_a -> /dev/block/sde8
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 abl_b -> /dev/block/sde32
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 abl_log -> /dev/block/sde67
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 aging_kernel -> /dev/block/sde64
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 aging_mod -> /dev/block/sde65
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 android_log -> /dev/block/sde69
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 1970-04-15 15:06 aop_a -> /dev/block/sde1
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 aop_b -> /dev/block/sde25
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 apdp -> /dev/block/sde51
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 1970-04-15 15:06 bluetooth_a -> /dev/block/sde5
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 bluetooth_b -> /dev/block/sde29
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 boot_a -> /dev/block/sde11
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 boot_b -> /dev/block/sde35
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 1970-04-15 15:06 cdt -> /dev/block/sdd2
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 cmnlib64_a -> /dev/block/sde13
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 cmnlib64_b -> /dev/block/sde37
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 cmnlib_a -> /dev/block/sde12
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 cmnlib_b -> /dev/block/sde36
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 config -> /dev/block/sda11
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 1970-04-15 15:06 ddr -> /dev/block/sdd3
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 devcfg_a -> /dev/block/sde14
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 devcfg_b -> /dev/block/sde38
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 devinfo -> /dev/block/sde49
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 dip -> /dev/block/sde50
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 1970-04-15 15:06 dsp_a -> /dev/block/sde9
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 dsp_b -> /dev/block/sde33
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 dtbo_a -> /dev/block/sde17
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 dtbo_b -> /dev/block/sde41
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 featenabler_a -> /dev/block/sde22
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 featenabler_b -> /dev/block/sde46
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 1970-04-15 15:06 frp -> /dev/block/sda5
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 1970-04-15 15:06 fsc -> /dev/block/sdf5
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 1970-04-15 15:06 fsg -> /dev/block/sdf4
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 1970-04-15 15:06 hyp_a -> /dev/block/sde3
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 hyp_b -> /dev/block/sde27
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 hyp_log -> /dev/block/sde71
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 imagefv_a -> /dev/block/sde23
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 imagefv_b -> /dev/block/sde47
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 kernel_log -> /dev/block/sde68
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 keymaster_a -> /dev/block/sde10
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 keymaster_b -> /dev/block/sde34
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 1970-04-15 15:06 keystore -> /dev/block/sda4
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 limits -> /dev/block/sde54
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 limits-cdsp -> /dev/block/sde55
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 logdump -> /dev/block/sde57
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 logfs -> /dev/block/sde56
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 logo_a -> /dev/block/sde24
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 logo_b -> /dev/block/sde48
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 1970-04-15 15:06 mdm1m9kefs1 -> /dev/block/sdf7
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 1970-04-15 15:06 mdm1m9kefs2 -> /dev/block/sdf8
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 1970-04-15 15:06 mdm1m9kefs3 -> /dev/block/sdf6
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 1970-04-15 15:06 mdm1m9kefsc -> /dev/block/sdf9
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 mdm1oemnvbktmp -> /dev/block/sde63
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 1970-04-15 15:06 mdm_oem_dycnvbk -> /dev/block/sda7
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 1970-04-15 15:06 mdm_oem_stanvbk -> /dev/block/sda8
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 1970-04-15 15:06 mdmddr -> /dev/block/sdd4
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 1970-04-15 15:06 mdtp_a -> /dev/block/sde7
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 mdtp_b -> /dev/block/sde31
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 1970-04-15 15:06 mdtpsecapp_a -> /dev/block/sde6
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 mdtpsecapp_b -> /dev/block/sde30
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 metadata -> /dev/block/sda19
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 1970-04-15 15:06 misc -> /dev/block/sda3
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 1970-04-15 15:06 modem_a -> /dev/block/sde4
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 modem_b -> /dev/block/sde28
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 1970-04-15 15:06 modemdump -> /dev/block/sda9
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 1970-04-15 15:06 modemst1 -> /dev/block/sdf2
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 1970-04-15 15:06 modemst2 -> /dev/block/sdf3
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 msadp -> /dev/block/sde52
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 multiimgoem_a -> /dev/block/sde19
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 multiimgoem_b -> /dev/block/sde43
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 multiimgqti_a -> /dev/block/sde20
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 multiimgqti_b -> /dev/block/sde44
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 op1 -> /dev/block/sde66
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 op2 -> /dev/block/sda10
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 opproduct_a -> /dev/block/sda12
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 opproduct_b -> /dev/block/sda13
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 1970-04-15 15:06 param -> /dev/block/sda6
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 1970-04-15 15:06 persist -> /dev/block/sda2
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 qsee_log -> /dev/block/sde70
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 qupfw_a -> /dev/block/sde15
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 qupfw_b -> /dev/block/sde39
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 rawdump -> /dev/block/sda22
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 recovery_a -> /dev/block/sda15
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 recovery_b -> /dev/block/sda16
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 reserve1 -> /dev/block/sde72
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 reserve2 -> /dev/block/sde73
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 reserve3 -> /dev/block/sde74
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 reserve4 -> /dev/block/sde75
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   14 1970-04-15 15:06 sda -> /dev/block/sda
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   14 1970-04-15 15:06 sdb -> /dev/block/sdb
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   14 1970-04-15 15:06 sdc -> /dev/block/sdc
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   14 1970-04-15 15:06 sdd -> /dev/block/sdd
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   14 1970-04-15 15:06 sde -> /dev/block/sde
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   14 1970-04-15 15:06 sdf -> /dev/block/sdf
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 secdata -> /dev/block/sde60
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 spunvm -> /dev/block/sde53
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 1970-04-15 15:06 ssd -> /dev/block/sda1
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 storsec_a -> /dev/block/sde58
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 storsec_b -> /dev/block/sde76
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 super -> /dev/block/sda14
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 1970-04-15 15:06 tz_a -> /dev/block/sde2
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 tz_b -> /dev/block/sde26
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 uefisecapp_a -> /dev/block/sde18
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 uefisecapp_b -> /dev/block/sde42
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 uefivarstore -> /dev/block/sde59
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 userdata -> /dev/block/sda23
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 vbmeta_a -> /dev/block/sde16
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 vbmeta_b -> /dev/block/sde40
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 vbmeta_system_a -> /dev/block/sda17
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 vbmeta_system_b -> /dev/block/sda18
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 vm-data -> /dev/block/sde62
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 vm-keystore -> /dev/block/sde61
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 vm-linux_a -> /dev/block/sde21
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 vm-linux_b -> /dev/block/sde45
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 vm-system_a -> /dev/block/sda20
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 1970-04-15 15:06 vm-system_b -> /dev/block/sda21
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 1970-04-15 15:06 xbl_a -> /dev/block/sdb1
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 1970-04-15 15:06 xbl_b -> /dev/block/sdc1
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 1970-04-15 15:06 xbl_config_a -> /dev/block/sdb2
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 1970-04-15 15:06 xbl_config_b -> /dev/block/sdc2
```

The command below produces an empty 71 byte archive.

```
$ adb -s XXXXXXXX exec-out 'cat /dev/block/mmcblk0 | gzip' > backup/partitions/mmcblk0.tar.gz
$ ls -shlap backup/partitions/mmcblk0.tar.gz
4.0K -rw-rw-r-- 1 tanhok tanhok 71 Aug  5 18:26 backup/partitions/mmcblk0.tar.gz
```

Which one of those is "the new `mmcblk0`"? Which one should I pull to have a full backup of my device stock firmware as an `.img` file?

Comment: sda - sdf or /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name

Comment: In Android / Linux kernel drivers `mmcblk` is the naming convention for eMMC flash storage block devices. `sd[X]` is the convention for the new UFS chips, like HDDs and SSDs. `mmcblk0` is not a partition, but the whole flash storage block device.

Comment: @IrfanLatif and how could it be referenced then? Where is it mounted at?

Comment: Partitions aren't mounted. Filesystems are.

Comment: @IrfanLatif how do I pull it from my phone then?

Comment: What's "it"? To have a complete dump of your flash, pull all of the `sd[a|b|c|d|e|f]` block devices. But if you don't know why to or how to or what to backup, the backup won't be of any use to you, in most cases.

Comment: your user data is *userdata* (encrypted), ROM is *boot_a* + *super*, firmware is all other partitions

Comment: @alecxs thank you very much. Will test this and mark your message as answer. Can you also link the docs if you have any?

Comment: very good explanation of android partitions on xda-developers

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/215683/trying-to-understand-the-options-in-twrp-backup#comment276228_215683