# What's the difference between preloader_raw.img, preloader_ufs.img and preloader_emmc.img?

Tags: custom-roms, device-firmware, mediatek

I have a Xiaomi Redmi 9 phone, and in case of this device I use a custom ROM - crDroid. From time to time, I update the phone's firmware by downloading a corresponding firmware package from [xiaomifirmwareupdater.com](https://xiaomifirmwareupdater.com/firmware/lancelot/).

When you look inside the firmware package, you can see the following content:

```
Path = fw_lancelot_miui_LANCELOTEEAGlobal_V12.5.4.0.RJCEUXM_67a1671939_11.0.zip
Type = zip
Physical Size = 40808894

   Date      Time    Attr         Size   Compressed  Name
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2022-02-28 13:40:44 D....            0            0  META-INF
2022-02-28 13:40:40 .....       280488       171992  preloader_raw.img
2022-02-28 13:40:40 .....       282536       172052  preloader_ufs.img
2022-02-28 13:40:42 .....            1            3  type.txt
2022-02-28 13:40:40 .....          859          364  scatter.txt
2022-02-28 13:40:40 .....       282536       172052  preloader_emmc.img
2022-02-28 13:40:40 .....     59329408     35869684  md1img.img
2022-02-28 13:40:42 .....      2505440      2166963  tee.img
2022-02-28 13:40:42 .....        37984         7454  spmfw.img
2022-02-28 13:40:40 .....       352816       144110  scp.img
2022-02-28 13:40:42 .....       505616       483321  sspm.img
2022-02-28 13:40:24 .....      1302976       522804  lk.img
2022-02-28 13:40:22 D....            0            0  META-INF/com
2022-02-28 13:40:44 .....         1634         1144  META-INF/CERT.RSA
2022-02-28 13:40:42 .....         2217          999  META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
2022-02-28 13:40:42 .....         2270         1091  META-INF/CERT.SF
2022-02-28 13:40:42 D....            0            0  META-INF/com/android
2022-02-28 13:40:22 D....            0            0  META-INF/com/google
2022-02-28 13:40:24 D....            0            0  META-INF/com/google/android
2022-02-28 13:40:24 .....      2340536      1090127  META-INF/com/google/android/update-binary
2022-02-28 13:40:44 .....         3559          863  META-INF/com/google/android/updater-script
2022-02-28 13:40:22 .....          316          220  META-INF/com/android/metadata
2022-02-28 13:40:42 .....         1594         1077  META-INF/com/android/otacert
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2022-02-28 13:40:44           67232786     40806320  18 files, 5 folders
```

So I have the following questions:

1. Will the preloader be touched in any way when I flash this zip via TWRP/SHRP recovery?
2. What's the difference between `preloader_raw.img` , `preloader_ufs.img` and `preloader_emmc.img` ?
3. In the [fastboot ROMs](https://xiaomifirmwareupdater.com/miui/lancelot/) there's `preloader_lancelot.bin` which (according to the `scatter.txt` file) goes to:

> ```
>   partition_index: SYS0
>   partition_name: preloader
>   file_name: preloader_lancelot.bin
>   is_download: true
>   type: SV5_BL_BIN
>   linear_start_addr: 0x0
>   physical_start_addr: 0x0
>   partition_size: 0x80000
>   region: EMMC_BOOT1_BOOT2
>   storage: HW_STORAGE_EMMC
>   boundary_check: true
>   is_reserved: false
>   operation_type: BOOTLOADERS
>   is_upgradable: true
>   empty_boot_needed: false
>   combo_partsize_check: false
>   reserve: 0x00
> ```

Is this `preloader_lancelot.bin` file related anyhow to `preloader_raw.img`, `preloader_ufs.img` or `preloader_emmc.img` ?

Comment: compare checksum for files. read META-INF/com/google/android/updater-script

Comment: It looks like it depends on `get_storage_type()` -- I have no idea what that would be. But if true, then `preloader_ufs.img` is flashed to `/dev/block/mmcblk0boot1` and if false then `preloader_emmc.img` is flashed instead.

Comment: https://fossbytes.com/what-is-ufs-storage

Comment: It's not about the difference between the two, but how do I know which one is used?

Comment: with get_storage_type() probably ;) or check partitions https://android.stackexchange.com/q/240767