# Completely restoring all partitions on my phone to factory after flashing custom ROMs?

Tags: rom-flashing, factory-reset, restore, xiaomi, device-firmware

I own a xiaomi phone for 2 years on which i flashed several roms and vendors via twrp. When i lately wanted to go back to stock (more accurate the stock rom the phone was released with, miui 10 pie) i had to discover that there are partitions like persistent which aren't replaced when clean flashing roms even tough i do a fastboot flash with Mi tool.

My persistnet got corrupted (sensors like gyroscope is broken) at this process and i found already a few tips how to solve it.

But my real question is, how do i completely restore my phone as i would unbox it ? With all the stuff like persistent and what ever is untouched by clean flashing roms and can get corrupted (and may you can tell me what remains untouched and it is used for/worth restoring).

Comment: restore your backup

Comment: I dont have a backup as it isnt a new phone, but used one unluckily and i have instantly flashed a custom on it.

Comment: simple answer one can't restore partitions that neither included in firmware/ROM nor in backup

Comment: @alecxs        do does partitions which arent included in rom change when the user uses his phone ? Btw i have found a lot of stuff which is included in rom but not flashed like ifaa.img, persist.img, dummy.img, hypvm.mbn ...

Comment: on stock android most partitions are read-only + protected by locked bootloader

Comment: very good explanation of android partitions on xda-developers
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/215683/trying-to-understand-the-options-in-twrp-backup#comment276228_215683

Comment: open that partition image files with HxD hex editor and take a look inside. if you feel that should be flashed onto device you can try *'adb push <file> /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/<partition>'* or copy file to MicroSD Card and from within shell *'dd if=file of=/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/<partition>'* **but do backup with** `adb pull` **first**