# Which partitions to back up for a "complete" backup?

Tags: adb, backup, partitions

I have a Galaxy S10e running crDroid 13. I don't have TWRP on it (since it had to be installed from the custom LineageOS recovery), but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29442630/copy-full-disk-image-from-android-to-computer explains how to get partition images usind `adb pull`.

Which partitions do I need to back up for a "complete" backup, though? `ls -la /dev/block/by-name` shows many:

```
boot -> /dev/block/sda14
bota0 -> /dev/block/sda1
bota1 -> /dev/block/sda2
bota2 -> /dev/block/sda8
bota3 -> /dev/block/sda24
cache -> /dev/block/sda28
cp_debug -> /dev/block/sda30
cpefs -> /dev/block/sdd1
dqmdbg -> /dev/block/sda22
dtb -> /dev/block/sda12
dtbo -> /dev/block/sda13
efs -> /dev/block/sda3
keydata -> /dev/block/sda21
keyrefuge -> /dev/block/sda20
keystorage -> /dev/block/sda6
misc -> /dev/block/sda19
nad_refer -> /dev/block/sda17
omr -> /dev/block/sda29
param -> /dev/block/sda4
persistent -> /dev/block/sda18
product -> /dev/block/sda27
radio -> /dev/block/sda16
recovery -> /dev/block/sda15
sda -> /dev/block/sda
sdb -> /dev/block/sdb
sdc -> /dev/block/sdc
sdd -> /dev/block/sdd
sde -> /dev/block/sde
sec_efs -> /dev/block/sda7
steady -> /dev/block/sda9
system -> /dev/block/sda25
uh -> /dev/block/sda10
uhcfg -> /dev/block/sda11
up_param -> /dev/block/sda5
userdata -> /dev/block/sda31
vbmeta -> /dev/block/sda23
vendor -> /dev/block/sda26
```

I don't know what most of them do, e.g. bota, cpefs, etc. I suppose I need **boot, system, recovery** and **userdata**, but what else?

It's also unclear to me where user files on "internal storage" (/sdcard) are stored. `userdata` is mounted as `/data`, but I don't see `/sdcard` listed in the output of `mount`. It does show this:

```
/data/media on /mnt/runtime/default/emulated type sdcardfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,gid=1015,multiuser,mask=6,derive_gid,default_normal)
/data/media on /mnt/runtime/read/emulated type sdcardfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,gid=9997,multiuser,mask=23,derive_gid,default_normal)
/data/media on /mnt/runtime/write/emulated type sdcardfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,gid=9997,multiuser,mask=7,derive_gid,default_normal)
/data/media on /mnt/runtime/full/emulated type sdcardfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,gid=9997,multiuser,mask=7,derive_gid,default_normal)
```

but I don't understand how that works, because `/data/media` seems to be a regular directory and not a device file.

Comment: Since the days when `/sdcard` changed from a real sdcard to an emulated one it is simply a directory on the user data partition. And the sdcard directory is just a soft link in the file-system. Just look at it using `ls -l /` to see the link targets.

Comment: very good explanation of android partitions on xda-developers https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/215683/trying-to-understand-the-options-in-twrp-backup#comment276228_215683 bear in mind that dump of userdata (+ metadata) partition is encrypted, and becomes useless on factory reset

Comment: @Robert thanks, OK, so `userdata` should actually include all user data then. @alecxs Ah maybe that explains why I cannot open the userdata image using the Linux Disks utility! It detects an ext4 filesystem, but fails to mount it with a generic error ("cannot mount /dev/loop0 read-only (udisks-error-quark, 0)"). I have stock ROM files, but don't know how to get the partition names from those. It's just the standard AP, BL, CP, CSC and HOME_CSC tar files.

Comment: OK, I opened the tar files in in 7z and opened the .pit file in GGSM_PIT_VIEWER [https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiN8Z.png], but both include `userdata`, which obviously **does** need to be backed up. So I'm not sure how this tells me which partitions to back up.

Comment: Also, with userdata being encrypted this would make the backup useless after a factory reset, as I understand, so perhaps this backup method is not so useful after all. Maybe booting to TWRP via `adb fastboot boot twrp.img` and doing backups from TWRP would be a better option, after all.

Comment: No, userdata _is_ included in the stock ROM's partition list - though its length is 0. vbmeta and recovery are also included, of course, but I know I replaced those when flashing, so need to back those up. Basically the stock ROM includes a lot of partitions and I'm not sure which of those are still stock on my device and which have been replaced by flashing my custom ROM (crDroid) or otherwise modified.

Comment: on screenshot I can see bota persistent misc keyrefuge keydata